# Ruby on Rails set up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently following the [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) to create a blog app.
When I run.

```
ruby -v #ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin16].
```

I have already ran:

```
gem install rails
bundle install
```

I just reached step 4.1, then I ran

```
bin/rails server
```

and I am encountering the following error

[image]

Comment: it's a warning. the server is up.

Comment: goto localhost:3000

Comment: There is no error, is just a warning recommending you to update to Ruby 2.3.1. You can continue without any problem, or update Ruby to remove the messages.

Comment: Thank you all for the awesome answers. However, I was taken to a blank screen and the rails guide suggested that I should see a welcome screen. I will upgrade to 2.3.1 and see if it changes anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a warning, and not an error. It's clearly suggesting: **upgrade to 2.3.1**

The server is up and running anyway.

If you are using rvm, `rvm install ruby-2.3.1` will do it for you.

Comment: The error I had mentioned is in regards to when I go to localhost:3000, all I see is a blank page even after running bin/rails server. However, the guide said that I should be seeing a welcoming page from the rails community.

Comment: Tried updating Ruby version?